# PhpUnit 3.6.10 + NetBeans 7.1: Good test throws exception

Tags: phpunit, netbeans-7.1

In cmdline everything is OK:

```
d:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\Tests>phpunit TestStub.php
PHPUnit 3.6.10 by Sebastian Bergmann.

.

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 2.75Mb

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
```

Called in NetBeans7.1:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPUnit_Framework_Exception' with message 'Could not find class "" in "D:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.1\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php".' in D:\xampp\php\PEAR\PHPUnit\Util\Skeleton\Test.php:123
Stack trace:
0 D:\xampp\php\PEAR\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php(157): PHPUnit_Util_Skeleton_Test->__construct('', 'D:\Program File...')
1 D:\xampp\php\PEAR\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php(130): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run(Array, true)
2 D:\xampp\php\phpunit(46): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main()
3 {main}
thrown in D:\xampp\php\PEAR\PHPUnit\Util\Skeleton\Test.php on line 123
```

I think this is a NetBeans issue. 
If I run:

```
d:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.1\php\phpunit>phpunit NetBeansSuite.php run=d:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\Tests\TestStub.php
PHPUnit 3.6.10 by Sebastian Bergmann.

.

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 2.75Mb

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
```

It's OK. But if I give the test directory, it fails.

```
d:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.1\php\phpunit>phpunit NetBeansSuite.php run=d:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\Tests\

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPUnit_Framework_Exception' with message 'Could not find class "" in "D:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.1\php\phpunit\NetBea
nsSuite.php".' in D:\xampp\php\PEAR\PHPUnit\Util\Skeleton\Test.php:123
Stack trace:
0 D:\xampp\php\PEAR\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php(157): PHPUnit_Util_Skeleton_Test->__construct('', 'D:\Program File...')
1 D:\xampp\php\PEAR\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php(130): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run(Array, true)
2 D:\xampp\php\phpunit(46): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main()
3 {main}
thrown in D:\xampp\php\PEAR\PHPUnit\Util\Skeleton\Test.php on line 123
```

Any temporary solution?

Comment: Grrr..    line 118 in "d:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.1\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php" shows the solution
`return self::rglob("*[Tt]est.php", $run.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);`

Test filename must be ended ...Test.php

Comment: I've personally found that the PHPUnit support in NetBeans is problematic at best and have ditched it in favor of running unit tests at the command line instead.

Comment: Did you point NetBeans to your `bootstrap.php` and/or `phpunit.xml` files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When running PHPUnit against a single file it will always open the file and look for a test case inside of it.

When running it against a directory (what netbeans does) it will only look into files that end in `*Test.php` (unless something else is specified in the phpunit.xml).

If it can't find any Tests it will try to look into the `$TestSuiteName` folder and `{$TestSuiteName}.php` files hence the error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPUnit_Framework_Exception' with message 'Could not find class ""

as it is looking for a "not named" test suite in the netbeans phpunit harness. The error message is really not helping you out there :)

The general suggestion would be to create a `phpunit.xml` and point Netbeans to it.

On a more personal note: From the phpunit support in the major IDEs Netbeans does quite a lot of things right and works well for a lot of people so don't let this bump discourage you from using it from the IDE if thats what you want.